# Allow CORS on symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, nelmiocorsbundle

I recently needed to allow CORS and on my search for a solution I found `nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle`.

For the begging I can allow request from any origin, so this is my `app/config/config.yml`:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
        max_age: 3600
        origin_regex: false
```

It worked for GET requests only, any POST request returns:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I don't need necessarily to work with this bundle, at the begging i tried to uncomment `TRUSTED_HOSTS` and set it with my domain on `dotenv` file but it was for no use. Also I didn't found any help about this TRUSTED_HOSTS in docs.

So any help with this bundle or any other solution to CORS on symfony I would be glad.

---

As asked I'm updating with my current config of nelmiocors:

```
# app/config/config.yml

# Nelmio CORS Configuration
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/':
          origin_regex: true
          allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
          # allow_origin: ['^http://localhost:[0-9]+']
          allow_headers: ['*']
          allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
          # allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
          max_age: 3600
          # hosts: ['^api\.']
```

Comment: You could have a look at the recipe when you install the bundle with Symfony Flex. This is the default configuration : https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/nelmio/cors-bundle/1.5/config/packages/nelmio_cors.yaml

As you can see the .env file is also completed with the parameter CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN

Comment: Yes, I followed the recipe but it didn't work, after that I tried a specific route and got a different error, so I stepped back I asked for help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know what exactly was wrong, but as one of the comments helped (the person who helped might have deleted his own comment).

I end up with this configuration to Nelmio CORS:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

And after that cleared the cache from cli and manually and it worked.

*My guess on what I was doing wrong: When I first configured Nelmio CORS I didn't cleared the cache and consequently it didn't work. After that I tried some other combinations of configuration and it didn't work either even when I cleared the cache. This makes me thing that the code should work from the begging if i didn't forget to clear the cache, after this I used invalid configuration and obviously clearing the cache this wouldn't work. In sum, it was a beginners mistake.*

Comment: If somebody wants to see CORS headers via Postman or Direct browser link - you'll be unsuccessful. You must put Origin header to request, because otherwise CorsListener will not work. Details at Nelmio\CorsBundle\EventListener\CorsListener::onKernelRequest()

Comment: Can you please add the commands for clearing the CLI cache that you used?

Comment: @Quatsch sorry for the late answer. Probably it was `php bin/console cache:clear`.

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    origin_regex: true
    allow_origin: ['*']
    allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
    allow_headers: ['Accept','Authorization','Cache-Control','Content-Type','DNT','If-Modified-Since','Keep-Alive','Origin','User-Agent','X-Requested-With']
    expose_headers: ['Authorization']
    max_age: 3600
paths:
    '^/': ~
```