# Symfony React Cors issue

Tags: reactjs, docker, symfony, docker-compose, cors

I use `Symfony 5` and `React`, with `docker`.

Both container are on different docker-compose but on the same newtork, so they can see and ping each other.

Now I want to `POST` something on one of my api route, here is my request:

```
const handleSubmit = async function (e) {
        setError(null)
        setLoading(true)
        e.preventDefault()
        const data = new FormData(e.target)
        console.warn(data)
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://localhost:8443/authentication_token', {
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                },
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
            })

            console.warn(response)
            const responseData = await response.json()
            console.warn(responseData)
            onConnect(responseData)
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e)
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }
```

Then I'm getting the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:8443/authentication_token' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

So after some search I installed `nelmio package` to deal with cors, here is my `nelmio_cors.yml` file:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_methods: [ 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE' ]
        allow_headers: [ '*' ]
        expose_headers: [ 'Authorization']
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: true
        forced_allow_origin_value: ~
    paths:
        '^/':
            origin_regex: true
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: [ '*' ]
            allow_methods: [ 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'GET', 'DELETE' ]
            expose_headers: [ 'Link' ]
            max_age: 3600
```

And added the below line in my `.env`:

```
###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=(.*)
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###
```

And yet I get the same error and didn't manage to find an answer online.

Does anyone see what I've done wrong?

### UPDATE

I've changed my `nelmio_cors.yml` config to the one above

And still got issues with cors but a different error message now:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://localhost:8443/authentication_token", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
```

It seems react don't manage to find the route. Any idea why ?

### UPDATE 2

My `nelmio_cors.yaml` file now looks like that :

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/':
            origin_regex: true
            allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
```

`.env` contains:

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=(.*)
```

But on the route call I receive the following error :

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:8443/authentication_token' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

My response headers

```
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3001
cache-control: no-cache, private
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 451
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 22 Oct 2020 08:12:11 GMT
server: openresty/1.17.8.2
status: 404
vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Accept
x-debug-exception: Unable%20to%20find%20the%20controller%20for%20path%20%22%2Fauthentication_token%22.%20The%20route%20is%20wrongly%20configured.
x-debug-exception-file: %2Fsrv%2Fapi%2Fvendor%2Fsymfony%2Fhttp-kernel%2FHttpKernel.php:141
x-debug-token: 9b2891
x-debug-token-link: https://localhost:8443/_profiler/9b2891
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.11
x-previous-debug-token: 486328
x-robots-tag: noindex
```

`request header`:

```
:authority: localhost:8443
:method: POST
:path: /authentication_token
:scheme: https
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
content-length: 248
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarywFASHmBarrNFyL7Y
cookie: pma_lang=fr; phpMyAdmin=a18f394d8e7daaefba20691da57c4b58; io=Jh7QElIlIXLDeAYaAAAA
origin: http://localhost:3001
referer: http://localhost:3001/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.99 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I don't see that env var used anywhere in your config (and it looks mangled, maybe just by pasting here). Shouldn't you add it to the `allow_origin` array? Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544855).

Comment: The policy must be integrated in the responding system. Sorry, I cannot see if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a different environmental variable value for local development and for your production or non-production environments.

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/':
            origin_regex: true
            allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
```

For local development you may have the following env.

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=(.*)
```

For prod/non-prod you may want to list your web applications domains explicitly in order to be on a safe side.

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https://(www\.)?(site.domain.com|site2.domain.com)$
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my nelmio_cors and .env file, and my post, but I still get the same issue. Would you know any other way to fix that ?

Comment: Have you used the whole snippet I've posted? I can see the "hosts" definition in your config, it could be the cause of the issue, as your localhost doesn't have "api" prefix.

Comment: Yes, I've just updated my post again. Yes thanks I removed it. Now I get a new kind of error, still cors related sadly, as if react couldn't find the route, don't understand why

Comment: Your configuration is still very different from my snippet. It works for me in a pretty much similar case, so I can't see a reason why it shouldn't work for you. Please consider to use it as it is. And check your response CORS headers, it could be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: I made another update to my post to answer you. Maybe our projects differ in the docker implementations (I've updated that as well at the top of the issue). But I don't really see how that would impact cors really

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind to check the response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value, please?

Comment: Yes you can view it my post now

Comment: Perfect, thanks. From response perspective it looks legit. Please include request headers, especially the "origin" header value. Also, your response has 404 code and it's not related to CORS.

Comment: Yes I've dug that a bit further, I get the error `No route found for "GET /authentication_token": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)` from browser network error. The route only accept POST which is what I want. BUT the request is send w/ POST from react side, as seen in the headers, so I'm not understanding where this error might come from.

Comment: According to request headers, it definitely sends a POST request.

Comment: Yes, do you know where it could come from ?

Comment: I'd suggest to check your controller and route settings. Also, try to call the endpoint via Postman to make sure the problem is not related to React application.

Comment: Endpoint through postman works fine, my route setting is the one of the doc, and I got no Controller, as it is not specified in the doc either

Comment: Yeah, looks odd. It's definitely something on a backend application level. At least we've beaten CORS issue.

Comment: yes! Thanks for your help! I'm gonna start the whole process from the beggining on another branch, I'll let you know how it goes

Answer (score -1):

For those who have the same issue, the problem came from the frontend

The data I recovered and place in body :

```
const response = await fetch(
                'https://localhost:8443/authentication_token', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
                },
                body: data
            })
```

were not well formated, and for some reason the backend sent back weird errors.

So I hardcoded them and this final result work :

```
const data = "{\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"password\":\"test\"}";
            const response = await fetch(
                'https://localhost:8443/authentication_token', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
                },
                body: data
            })
```