# Using Symfony as a backend and getting CORS error

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony, cors-anywhere

From my React Frontend I send a request to my Symfony backend.(Previously it worked fine with a pure PHP backend) .

```
useEffect(() => {
              axios.get('http://localhost:8080/real_estate_refactored_backend/main').then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
            });
  });
```

The main in the URL is the route of my Symfony controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Estates;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class MainController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/main", name="main")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $estates = $entityManager->getRepository(Estates::class)->findAll();

        $response = new Response();
   

    $response->setContent(json_encode([
        'estates' => uniqid(),
    ]));

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return new Response($response);
    }
}
```

In Symfony the connection with the database went fine.

And eventhough I have installed the Nelmino CORS bundle in Symfony with the following configuration in the

nelmino_cors.yaml

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': null
```

I still get the following error message

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Hello, could you try to change the paths (in nelmio_cors.yaml) to: `'^/': ~` ?

Comment: And erasing tje other stuff? Yes I did with the same result.

Comment: Did you tried to clear your cache? As mentionned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54572925/1750964

Comment: Yes I tried but it doesn`t change a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Symfony (security) configured to use a session cookie for authention, add `allow_credentials: true` to `nelmio_cors.yaml`, and add `withCredentials: true` to the `axios` configuration object:

**`config/packages/nelmio_cors.yaml`**

```yaml
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: true
        # Your existing configuration...
```

**Your axios snippet**

```js
axios.get('/foo', { withCredentials: true });
```

Comment: Can you trell me where I have to go to do this config with cookies?

Comment: What I meant is that I assume you have symfony's `security.yaml` configured to use a firewall based on session/cookie authentication. You don't need to do anything with that configuration if that's the case. Just apply the examples I provided in `nelmio_cors.yaml` and your `axios` instance configuration (while keeping everything the same as in your original post). This allows your frontend and backend to share sessions/cookies despite being hosted on separate origins.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code to **.env**

```
###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^.*$
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###
```